# During compilation it is not asking for user input of rate and time

Tags: c

```
// Q. Find out the simple interest. 


#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    int principal, rate, time;

    printf("principal\n");
    scanf("% d", &principal);

    printf("rate\n");
    scanf("% d", &rate);

    printf("time\n");
    scanf("% d", &time);

    printf("Simple interest is %d", principal * rate * time / 100);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should it ask for input during compilation? Anyway, the format specifiers are incorrect - please remove the space from each `% d`.

Comment: obviosly during compilation the compiler just produces the output executable from the source code files and doesn't ask anything

Comment: Look out for compiler warnings. MS VC does tell you about the incorrect format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `scanf` to work, you need to remove the space between the % and the d in the format strings: `% d`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    int principal, rate, time;

    printf("principal\n");
    scanf("%d", &principal);

    printf("rate\n");
    scanf("%d", &rate);

    printf("time\n");
    scanf("%d", &time);

    printf("Simple interest is %d", principal * rate * time / 100);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, the program cannot ask for input during compilation. It will only ask for input when it is run.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy for pointing out the mistake and make it work. 
 @anton
Also, can you help me in making this program in less lines ?